# Passing Object Through Directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

This seems to have been asked a thousand different ways, but never quite like I am looking for, so here's mine (forgive me if there IS an answer to this already on SO):

Basically I am looking to pass an object through a custom directive to be evaluated by a function.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="app">
    <div ng-touchstart="process_person(person)" ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.name}}</div>
</div>
```

**Angular:**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('app',function(){
    $scope.people = [{name:'bob','id':49},{name:'al','id':50}];
    $scope.process_person = function(person){
        console.log('processing: ' + person.id);
        // result is person is undefined
    }
});
```

(from https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouchstart)

```
myApp.directive("ngTouchstart", function () {
  return {
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.bind('touchstart', onTouchStart);
      function onTouchStart(event) {
        var method = '$scope.' + $element.attr('ng-touchstart');
        $scope.$apply(function () {
          eval(method);
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

I am aware that the directive evaluates the attribute data as a string, I'm wondering how I would correct the above directive to pass my object through so that I might process it in my controller.

Comment: That's a puzzler. What happens when you set it up like `ng-touchstart="process_person($scope.person)"`?

Comment: Never mind. That throws an error "$scope not defined."

Comment: @AustinMullins, you know that you could delete a comment :)

Comment: @NewDev True, but now we know one thing that won't work.

Comment: Do you just want to invoke `process_person` function from the directive?

Comment: @NewDev I'd be happy to do that, but the function will exist in a different controller.  The "people" array lives in a child controller.  So, it seems sending an object would be the way I would like to do it.

Comment: @HowardZoopaloopa, I'm not sure I fully understand what you are saying. What is a child controller here? Take a look at my answer - it should address your issue as I understand it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, if you can afford it, is to create an isolate scope with `"&"`:

```
.directive("ngTouchstart", function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      onStart: "&ngTouchstart"
    },
    link: function(scope){
      //...
      function onTouchStart(event) {
        scope.onStart();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Since creating an isolate or a child scope is not without a cost (no other directive on the same element is allowed to create another scope), then you could use the `$parse` service:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
  var onStart = $parse(attrs.ngTouchstart);

  function onTouchStart(event){
    onStart(scope);
  }
}
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Y8rgMdxz02GHxxfALdq?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your controller code into a fiddle, and I kept getting this error:

> $scope is not defined

I didn't bother checking what line was throwing it because it shows up as happening inside Angular itself. However, I finally noticed something: `$scope` isn't passed into your controller constructor (at least not in the example shown here). Then things started working. I also use `$scope.$eval(method)` instead of `$scope.$apply( ... eval(method) ... )`. Finally, I place the definition of the `onTouchStart` function before the `bind` call, but that shouldn't matter. Here's the full example:

```
myApp.controller('app',function($scope){
    $scope.people = [{name:'bob','id':49},{name:'al','id':50}];
    $scope.process_person = function(person){
        console.log('processing: ' + person.id);
        return person;
    }
});

myApp.directive("ngTouchstart", function () {
  return {
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      function onTouchStart(event) {
        var method = $attrs['ng-touchstart'];
        $scope.$eval(method);
      };
      $element.bind('touchstart', onTouchStart);
    }
  };
});
```

[Here is that fiddle I mentioned](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/f6b0z9tt/).